# Convert an individual face location quadruple to to the area of image contained within the rectangle defined by that quadruple

Tags: python, face-recognition

This question is about a python3 face_recognition module.

For a `frame` from a live-streaming video, I have

`face_locs = face_recognition.face_locations(frame)`

What I want now is, for each `face` in `face_locs`, to convert `face` from a CSS-styled quadruple (top, right, bottom, left) to the area of the frame (as an image) bounded by the rectangle defined by that quadruple.

(The relevant part of) my code is following:

```
for face in face_locs:
    # TODO: convert face to a comparable image first
    res = face_recognition.compare_faces(face_encs_in_DB, face)
```

In the code above, what I can't do is denoted with TODO.

In my opinion (and I might be wrong), I should write a function `fix_face()` that takes `face` and, `np_arr` being the corresponding `numpy` array to `face`, the function should return `face_recognition.face_encodings(np_arr)[0]`.

Please, help me.

Answer (score 0):

I just found a solution to my problem after examining it for a couple of hours. Not sure if I should post this as an answer; if I'm wrong in doing so, please, warn me, so I can demote it to a comment. I'm posting it so that if anybody else runs into the same issue, they can get this solution.

Instead of

`face_locs = face_recognition.face_locations(frame)`,

write

`curr_face_encs = face_recognition.face_encodings(frame)`.

Then,

```
for face in curr_face_encs:
    res = face_recognition.compare_faces(face_encs_in_DB, face)
```

works.